# NSSortDescriptor error : " [NSSortDescriptor count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to setup `NSFetchedResultsController` with fetch request and I keep getting the error:

> "[NSSortDescriptor count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Below is my code. My model has only one record that I am trying to fetch. Also I am following Paul Heagarty's 2010-2011 Core Data demo video to set up my core data.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Temple"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
request.predicate = nil;
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.eventDatabase.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing `sortDescriptors` to your request and not `sortDescriptor` (without the `s`)? Sounds like what would happen if you provided a single NSSortDescriptor instance where an NSArray was expected.

Comment: Yeah checked that many times, changed the code and rewrote it. Could it be because there is only one record in the database

Comment: Thank you Tim..I resolved it..you made me look again in the code, I found anothor piece of code doing exactly what you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: probably should write your own answer and accept it or delete it... if you think it won't help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
// CAUSE OF ERROR: Assigning NSSortDescriptor to a property that expects an NSArray
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

// SOLUTION: Wrap your sort descriptor in an array, fixes error
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
```